# Case insensitive string filter in ext js

Tags: string, extjs, filter, case-insensitive

How can I make case insensitive string filter in extjs. Following is the corresponding grid column.

```
var columns = [{
           dataIndex: 'name',
           header: 'NAME',
           style: 'border: none;',
           id: 'name',
           sortable : true,
           width: 141,
           filter: {
               type: 'string'
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the sortType on the field in the model: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.SortTypes-method-asUCString

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    fields: [{
        name: 'name',
        sortType: 'asUCString'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Could you please integrate this with my post as I am new to extjs

Comment: You didn't post the relevant part of your code. You posted the column configuration, this needs to be set where you define the model, which is why I included the model.